# Can the LG 768 be encypted?

Tags: encryption, lg-optimus-l9

I have an LG 768 device. It is running Android 4.04 with Kernel version 3.0.21 and build number IMM76L. I can find no way to encrypt the device. None of the menus lead to an option to encrypt.

Has anyone figured out a way to encrypt this device?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, No.

<sup>[LG 768 User Manual](http://www.lg.com/lgecs.downloadFile.ldwf?DOC_ID=KROWM000425815&ORIGINAL_NAME_b1_a1=LG-P760_BAL_UG_Web_V1.0_121010.pdf&FILE_NAME=KROWM000425815.pdf&TC=DwnCmd)</sup>

LG devices don't have the Full Device Encryption capability with the stock ROM, but you can always install an app to deal with that:

## [SSE - Universal Encryption](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paranoiaworks.unicus.android.sse)

[image: SSE screenshot]

> Secret Space Encryptor (S.S.E.)
>
> - Password Manager, Message (Text) Encryption and File Encryption integrated in the all-in-one solution.
> - Store and manage all your passwords in one secure place protected with one Master Password.
> - Keep your messages, notes and other texts safe from unintended readers.
> - Securely encrypt your private and confidential files or whole folders.  Wiping (secure delete) feature is included.
> - Everything is encrypted using strong encryption algorithm: AES(Rijndael) 256bit, RC6 256bit, Serpent 256bit, Blowfish 256bit/448bit, Twofish 256bit and GOST 256bit ciphers are available.
> - Other Utils: Password Generator, Clipboard Cleaner, Algorithm Benchmark, ...
> - Minimal Permissions. No ads.
> - Cross-Platform (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, ...) GUI Version and Command Line Version of the File Encryptor is available on the application home page (download section).
> - This software is Open Source project – we have nothing to hide, so you can have securely hidden everything you need.
>     (as Open Source, this software is published under TSU - §740.13(e) encryption export license exception)